# 'No tests were found' error when trying to use Suites API with JUnit5 + Cucumber combination

Tags: junit5, cucumber-jvm, suite

It seems like no matter what combination of tags and paths I put along with Suites tag, the tests are not discoverable. The same happens if I don't use Suites tag and just run mvn test.

The only way that it works if I explicitly state the location of features inside junit-platform.properties file. That way the features are working just fine if I run mvn test. In case I use the exact same paths in Suite property tags, it doesn't.

Here are the screenshot of configuration(note that junit properties file is empty):

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVINK.png)

Some more details:

This is a content of a feature file

```
Scenario Outline: Verify user is unable to login with invalid credentials
    Given I am on Login page
    When I enter username "<username>" and password "<password>"
    Then I check login is not successful
    Examples:
      | username      | password  |
      | not_existing  | 123456789 |
      | invalid_login | test1234  |
```

This is how my POM file looks like

```
<properties>
    <log4j-core.version>2.20.0</log4j-core.version>
    <testng.version>6.14.3</testng.version>
    <owner.version>1.0.12</owner.version>
    <client-java.version>5.1.16</client-java.version>
    <playwright.version>1.35.0</playwright.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.26</lombok.version>
    <commons-csv.version>1.10.0</commons-csv.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.source>1.8</maven-compiler-plugin.source>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.target>1.8</maven-compiler-plugin.target>
    <junit-jupiter-api.version>5.9.3</junit-jupiter-api.version>
    <cucumber-java.version>7.13.0</cucumber-java.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M6</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <version>${log4j-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>${testng.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aeonbits.owner</groupId>
        <artifactId>owner</artifactId>
        <version>${owner.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.epam.reportportal</groupId>
        <artifactId>client-java</artifactId>
        <version>${client-java.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>${testng.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.playwright</groupId>
        <artifactId>playwright</artifactId>
        <version>${playwright.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-csv.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-jupiter-api.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-jupiter-api.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber-java.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber-java.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber-java.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.0-M1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example in the form of code and not an image.  In your case this should include Maven or Gradle config, as well as at least one cucumber scenario and the file structure.

Comment: If anything try the Java skeleton. It's a known working project. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje Yeah, I looked at that project before posting the question and I tried to line up the steps/feature files the similar way (please check the screenshot, maybe I don't understand the pattern) but it didn't help.

If I specify the path to feature file and glue to stepdef in junit platform property and then use the runner file and just specify the tag it works perfectly fine. 

Besides, am I wrong in assuming that we can have whatever stepdef/feature structure as long as we specify the correct path in the below Suite annotation?

Comment: @johanneslink added one of the feature files + POM snippet

Answer (score 0):

You've got quite a few problems going on.

1. You did not include the `junit-platform-suite` implementation as a dependency. Rather you included the `junit-platform-suite-api` which only contains the annotations not the actual test engine that executes the tests. Read the [JUnit 5 documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#overview) for a conceptual understanding.
2. Your JUnit dependencies don't converge. You are mixing v5.9.3 and v1.10.0-M1. Use the JUnit BOM to solve this. You can then declare your JUnit dependencies without version numbers.

```xml
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.9.3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-bom</artifactId>
                <version>7.13.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

3. Your runner class `CucumberRunner.java` does not end with `*Test.java` and because of that won't be picked up by Surefire. Rename it to `CucumberTest.java`

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

> By default, the Surefire Plugin will automatically include all test
> classes with the following wildcard patterns:
>
> "**/Test*.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that start with "Test".
>
> "**/*Test.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Test".
>
> "**/*Tests.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Tests".
>
> "**/*TestCase.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "TestCase".

Now these are just the problems I can see. It would be better to start with the [cucumber-java-skeleton](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton/) and transform it step by step into your project. If you run the tests after each change this should allow you to find the all problems that keep your project from working.

Comment: I changed the POM file the way you described (introduced BOMs) and used suite instead of suite-api and it worked! Now it even works if I change the folder structure and just specify the path (exactly the way I supposed it should work). Thanks a lot for the help!!

Comment: I have 2 questions if possible: 1. How does this BOM version of junit (5.9.3) works for the suite dependency if no such version exists in maven repository (1.10.x is the latest). 2. Is there a scenario where having Suite-api is useful without the actual runner? I would expect that running suite tag without the runner (basically like I did and had this issue) should at least log some warning so that people like me wouldn't fall into the same trap.

Comment: 1. You should look at the contents of the JUnit BOM.

Comment: 2a. The Suite API can also be used by the JUnit 4 runner for JUnit 5.

Comment: 2b. It is the same setup as the `junit-jupiter-api` and `junit-jupiter-engine` which are bundled in the `junit-jupiter` dependency. This is useful if you're bundling your tests as a dependency to be executed by someone else. The API changes less frequently than the implementation. This allows the third party to pick the engine version.

Comment: 2c. You may want to think about who does the execution and how they can know that the `@Suites` tag is executable.